# Problems with relative import and Python 3

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

First, I need to describe the environment I'm writing for. I'm writing Python code that will be loaded and executed by a Python runtime running within a CAD application.  The CAD application uses Python as its scripting engine.  As a result, I don't have access to the Python runtime and as a good citizen to all other scripts shouldn't modify any system settings.  My script is just one of many that are loaded and running.

This all works fine except when I want to use non-standard libraries.  In that case, I need to install a local copy of the library for my script to access.  The problem I'm having is that most libraries expect to be installed and added to the sys path which is something I shouldn't do because it could create conflicts with what other scripts are doing.  What I'm attempting to do instead is to set up a local copy of the library(s) and then edit their source so their imports are relative and they don't depend on the sys path. That way my program will have its own local copy of the libraries and not depend on anything else and won't disturb any other scripts.

I'm using the -t option of PIP to install Requests and PyOpenSSL into a "Packages" subfolder in my script folder.  Here's an abbreviated list of what I have.

```
RequestsTest/
    RequestsTest.py 
    Packages/
        OpenSSL/
            cryptography/
                x509/
                    __init__.py
                    base.py
                hazmat/
                    __init__.py
                    backends/
                        __init__.py
                        interfaces.py
                        openssl/
                            __init__.py
                            backend.py
                            x509.py
            OpenSSL/
                __init__.py
                SSL.py
        Requests/
            chardet/
                __init__.py
            requests/
                __init__.py
            urllib3/
                __init__.py
                request.py
                contrib/
                    __init__.py
                    pyopenssl.py
                util/
                    __init__.py
                    request.py
                    ssl_.py
```

Although it's tedious to track down the various import statements and make then relative, it does seem to work.  However, I'm having problems with one particular set of imports.

In Packages/Requests/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py it contains the following imports, which I've modified:

```
from ....OpenSSL.OpenSSL import SSL 
from ....OpenSSL.cryptography import x509
```

They were originally:

```
from OpenSSL import OpenSSL.SSL
from cryptography import x509
```

I get the error "ImportError: No module named 'OpenSSL'" for the first line and "ImportError: No module named 'cryptography'" for the second line.  I'm fairly certain the path is correct because if I change the number of dots I get the no module named error but it lists the full path of the what it's trying to load and not just the name of the module.

I would appreciate some help with this specific issue but can also use some overall advice of how to set up and use private copies of libraries.  Remember that my program is just one of many that the system is loading changing the system or setting up a virtual environment is not an option.

Comment: this sounds like an absolute nightmare....how is someone else supposed to maintain this?

Comment: I don't buy that "setting up a virtual environment is not an option".  That's exactly what you should be doing here, and if you can write to your user space at all then it *is* an option.

Comment: My program is loaded by the CAD system so I have no option of setting up a virtual environment but hopefully, I'm wrong and it can be done.

And you're correct about maintenance.  It is a nightmare but I'm not seeing any other options.

Comment: A virtual env itself is a separate folder that contains all the site-packages etc. and is easy to maintain as well. It is isolated from the other Python envs and does not cause any conflicts with other system packages. Setting up docker containers is another option and in my opinion the best one, if its possible to setup one in your env.

Comment: What is this CAD application?

Comment: @amanb, thank you for the input.  The problem that I have is that in my case I don't have my own environment but have to "play" with everyone else within the Fusion 360 Python environment.  Because of that, it's best if my program is completely self-contained, other than using system libraries so that I don't mess up the environment for others.

Comment: @FabienP, The CAD application is Fusion 360. It's running it's own Python interpreter and loads and runs python programs within that interpreter. I don't have any control over the Python runtime or the loading of my program. With a Python virtual environment, doesn't it have it's own private Python interpreter? I don't have that luxury.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [localimport](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/py-localimport) module, which seems to be a solution for your particular use case. From the README:

> Given your Python script, application or plugin comes with a directory that contains modules for import, you can use localimport to keep the global importer state clean.
>
> ```
> app.py
> res/modules/
>   some_package/
>     __init__.py
>
>
> # app.py
> with localimport('res/modules') as _importer:
>     import some_package
>     assert 'some_package' not in sys.modules
> ```

The tagline is "Isolated import of Python Modules for embedded applications." so it seems pretty relevant.

When using that module, the following may help keep things neat:

1. Put your actual script logic into its own file.
2. Have a wrapper script (which will be the one loaded by the CAD software) which does `localimport` as mentioned in the README then does a relative import of your module. If your module gets big enough maybe put it into its own package and consume it in the same way as everything else (just do `from RequestsTest import *` in the body of the `with localimport(): ...`.
3. Try to have a clear boundary between the source code you write and the final organized set of files required to use that source code in the context of the CAD Python runtime. It is OK to have a build/packaging step that creates the `localimport` script, downloads the required packages, etc. It's better even because then it is automated and not something that was done manually that someone in the future may have to recreate.

Comment: This seems to work, although it's bending my initial requirement of not changing anything about the system. It's just that in this case the system path is being managed and cleaned up once I'm done.